# Printing to screen kernel basics

Tags: c, optimization, flags, video-card

This code works with -O flag but don't works without -O flag and also don't works with -O2 and -O3 flag:

```
void putc(char c)
{

  static char *video = 0xb8000;

  *video = c;
  //video+=2;

}

void puts(char * s)
{

  for(;*s;) putc(*s++);

}

void start_kernel(void)
{

  putc('a');

  for(;;);

}
```

also this code displays nothing without flags, with -O flag and -O2 flag although it differs by one line after writing the character into the buffer:

```
void putc(char c)
{

  static char *video = 0xb8000;

  *video = c;
  video+=2;

}

void puts(char * s)
{

  for(;*s;) putc(*s++);

}

void start_kernel(void)
{

  putc('a');

  for(;;);

}
```

I'm using GRUB to load my "kernel" so I'm pretty sure that A20 line is unlocked and ...

I don't know what's going on...

Comment: Try making `video` `volatile`.

Comment: after making video volatile it runs succesfully with -O2 and -O3 flag. Second code still don't works.

Comment: In what way does it still not work?

Comment: First code displays a on the screen. Second code displays nothing on the screen.

Comment: try inserting video[1] = 0xf0; before the “video += 2”.   The standard display is not an array of chars, rather it is alternating char, attribute.

Comment: after adding video[1] = 0xf0; nothing changes